# Disk read/write?

Tags: macos, terminal

I am on OSX Mountain Lion. Using terminal commands/system console how do I get the total number of *bytes* written a read from the boot drive?

I am aware of the `top` command. However this gives the number of MB read/wrote not the number of bytes. A MB value isn't precise enough.

Answer (score 0):

[iotop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/iotop.1m.html) does give the number of bytes. Another option might be the [Disk Monitor Instrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/DiskMonitorInstrument/DiskMonitorInstrument.html) from the Instrument Analysis Tools that come with [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/).